# How to Select foreign key names instead of number in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I have the following situation:
One table called cad (id, name, gender, age, fok_professional, fok_agegroup, fok_ativity) and other table called professional (id, name), agegroup (id, desc), 
ativity (id, name);
How to select the name value instead number as generally is presented in simple query: For exemple:

```
SELECT * FROM cad
```

output is:

```
id -> 1;
name -> Teste;
gender -> Male;
age -> 22;
fok_professional -> 1;
fok_agegroup -> 4;
fok_ativity -> 2;
```

instead I would like:

```
id -> 1;
name -> Teste;
gender -> Male;
age -> 22;
fok_professional -> Administrator;
fok_agegroup -> Age 19 55;
fok_ativity -> Testestetstats;
```

How to get the values name ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want something like this, using SQL JOINs to connect the tables together :

```
SELECT
   cad.id, cad.name, cad.gender, cad.age,
   professional.name,
   agegroup.desc,
   ativity.name
FROM cad INNER JOIN professional ON cad.fok_professional = professional.id
         INNER JOIN agegroup ON cad.fok_agegroup = agegroup.id
         INNER JOIN ativity ON cad.fok_ativity = ativity.id
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the JOIN statement on tables cad, professionnal, agegroup and activity ON fok_XXX=XXX.id

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have appropriate permissions on the database that those tables belong to, if you want to be able to be able to just call something as simple as `SELECT * FROM sometable` to produce that sort of output, you may want to consider creating a view, then joining the two other tables that contain the human-readable rows in your view query.

Luckily for you, SQL Server Management Studio has a simple view designer which can help you in this regard. To access it, expand the database you want to create the view for in the Object Explorer, right-click Views, then click New View. Once you add the three tables you need into the View Designer, it will automatically create the required joins for you, assuming the relationships on each table are set up properly.

If you don't have SSMS, or you're not sure what views are, or why they're useful for your particular situation, you should review the [SQL Views](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa214068(v=sql.80).aspx) topic on TechNet. If you're not sure what joins are, or why tabular relationships are important, then you should consider brushing up on relational database theory a bit.

Comment: Unnecessary to complicate the matter. A simple join will give him what he wants

Comment: That's true, from the way they worded the question I assumed they wanted something akin to a view to get what they needed. If that's not the case, then yes, a join will do wonders.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use inner join between those three tables.
Try this:

```
SELECT C.ID,
C.NAME,
C.GENDER,
C.AGE,
P.NAME AS [FOK_PROFESSIONAL],
A.DESC AS [FOK_AGEGROUP],
AT.NAME AS [FOK_ATIVITY]
FROM CAD C
INNER JOIN PROFESSIONAL P
ON C.FOK_PROFESSIONAL = P.ID
INNER JOIN AGEGROUP A
ON C.FOK_AGEGROUP = A.ID
INNER JOIN ATIVITY AT
ON C.FOK_ATIVITY = AT.ID
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use above solutions or you can use the following known as `Common Table Expressions (CTEs)` for more readability.

```
WITH C AS
(
SELECT
   CAD.id, CAD.name, CAD.gender, CAD.age,
   PRO.name,
   AG.desc,
   AT.name
FROM CAD INNER JOIN professional As PRO ON CAD.fok_professional = PRO.id
         INNER JOIN agegroup As AG ON CAD.fok_agegroup = AG.id
         INNER JOIN ativity As AT ON CAD.fok_ativity = AT.id
)

SELECT * FROM C;
```